# Achievements icon fell down in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Having left the app for several hours after viewing a question, re-launching it reloaded the question I'd been viewing. Upon tapping back, the Achievements icon in the top-right had shifted down a bit. I took a screenshot, then refreshed the view, which then showed I had reputation changes.

Most likely, the icon was updated with the reputation change before closing the app. Upon restoring the view the `+10` was forgotten but the icon shift was not.

> [image]

Comment: ...from heavens to the ground!.. *is falling*, you wanted to say.

Comment: No, it only fell once. It’s back in its customary place now.